# Git slow fetch on new server

Tags: git

I have an automated deployment from source control that works roughly as follows:

1. `git fetch`
2. For every branch that has deployment information:

   1. `git reset --hard`
   2. `git checkout origin/branch-to-be-deployed`
   3. `rsync worktree targetdir`

This worked fine on our old server. However we recently switched to a new server and the `git fetch` step is incredibly slow, about 30-45 seconds. On the old server it did not slow down.

The rest of the git commands run fine. On our own computers . The new server has orders of magnitude better hardware and comparable network speeds. It is a VM though.

git gc or prune does not help, deleting the repo and doing a fresh clone does improves the speeds a little, but only to about 30s. The git version on the old server is 1.7.2, I've tried both 1.7.10 and 1.9.1 on the new server. I've also tried persistent connections but that doesn't help.

I've got no idea what's causing this, any suggestions?